# AS2 code to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, effect, actionscript-2

So i have a problem. I found a cool old tv grain code (here :http://www.republicofcode.com/tutori...ash/old_grain/), but its written in AS2, and i want to convert it to AS3. So heres the original script

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
_x = random(640);
_y = random(480);
_rotation = random(360);
_alpha = random(100);
_xscale = nue;
_yscale = nue;
nue = random(65);
}
```

My re-wrote version:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,start);
function start (e:Event):void{
x = Math. random()*640;
y = Math.random()*480;
rotation = Math.random()*360;
alpha = Math.random()*100;
scaleX = nue;
scaleY = nue;
nue = Math.random()*65;
```

But it says : 1120: Access of undefined property nue. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Hey guys!
Thank you for your help! I'm "working" with flash for 2 days so you both saved my life. I tried to solve my problem, and read about it but since my first language is not English it was a bit complicated! So thanks again,
A girl from Hungary
BTW. this is the final code

```
var nue:Number= 65;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
function update(event:Event):void {
x = Math. random()*640;
y = Math.random()*480; 
rotation = Math.random()*360;
alpha = Math.random()*10; 
nue = Math.random()*65; 
scaleX = nue;
scaleY = nue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to declare `nue` as a variable:

```
var nue:Number=1;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function update(event:Event):void {
    x = Math. random()*640;   // I think 640 must be stage.stageWidth
    y = Math.random()*480;    // and 480 must be stage.stageHeight
    rotation = Math.random()*360;
    alpha = Math.random();   // In AS2 alpha goes from 0 to 100 in AS3 goes from 0 to 1
    scaleX = nue;
    scaleY = nue;
    nue = Math.random()*65;
}
```

Comment: I -1'd you by accident, lots of tabs open, sorry about that. Though you are still using `nue` before you are defining it here. I can't undo the vote until you edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

In AS3 you cannot have a variable with no value and expect it to have one. You should give it a value or set it as undefined. 
You use `nue` at the end of your function, then you give it a value, it needs to be the other way around:

```
var nue:Number;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function update(event:Event):void {
    x = Math. random()*640;
    y = Math.random()*480;    
    rotation = Math.random()*360;
    alpha = Math.random();   
    nue = Math.random()*65; // set nue 
    scaleX = nue;           // then use it
    scaleY = nue;
}
```

Also note that the `alpha` property in AS3 has a range of 0 to 1 inclusive, not 0 to 100.

Comment: You don't need to set nue before using it, maybe he want to use the LAST value of nue and THEN set it again for using it the NEXT frame. I think the best is to set it and then use it, but not all solutions MUST BE THE SAME and NOT ALL OF US MUST write programs the same way.

Comment: WHAT'S WITH ALL THE CAPS LOCKS, It's very good practice to not use variables that haven't yet been defined, it's even better to say `var nue:Number = undefined` so you know there is a reason for it. I merely gave an example of where you could set `nue`. Chill out!

Comment: P.S. I'm not asking you to edit your answer to be like mine, I'm just saying I cannot undo my mistaken downvote unless you edit something in your question, SO is not allowing me.